# Как отследить смену url и поставить на смену событие?

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, url

Как отследить смену url и поставить на смену событие?
Использую html5 mode angularjs

Comment: событие onpagehide ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438698/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0