# Отслеживание изменения адреса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Дано: слайдер (photoswipe).

При смене картинки у нас меняется url без перезагрузки страницы. Дальше больше. Есть желание поставить рядом с картинкой баннер. Баннер находится в iframe с айдишником. Обновлять баннер нет никакой проблемы.

```
 $('#id').attr('src', $('#id').attr('src'));
```

Хочу привязать выше указанную функцию к смене urla. Все работает, если вешаю это событие на какой-либо клик. Но нам нужно следить за изменениями адреса. Буду очень рад помощи.

Перелопатил половину интернета. Что-то около

```
window.onhashchange
```

Comment: Какой функцией меняете урл? В ней и поставьте смену баннера.

Comment: Так а чем `window.onhashchange` не угодил?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте довольно простой jQuery плагин http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

```
$(window).hashchange(function () {
        var hash = location.hash;
        var res = (hash.replace(/^#!\//, '') || 'blank');
        console.log('hashchange', res);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я хотел без сторонних плагинов.

Answer (score 1):

предварительно сформировать uri, после чего передать в метод:

```
var stateParameters = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateParameters, "New page title", "/category/tech/page/2");
```

Перехватить событие изменения url можно с помощью метода:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    // current href: document.location.pathname
    Application.updateState();
});
```

Comment: Интересно. А можно подробнее?
Допустим, у меня есть сайт: site.ru
Затем я захожу на стараницу: site.ru/pages/555
На странице клацаю на картинку и получаю: site.ru/pages/555#&gid=1&pid=1. Другая картинка имеет адрес:site.ru/pages/555#&gid=1&pid=2. ну и так далее. Как мне дернуть iframe с рекламой, при смене картинки?